# trouble to insert an csv file data to mysql table

Tags: php, html, mysql, csv

I want to get a file from file input element in html. I set the name attribute in input type file.
But I can't get it. Please help me to slove this problem. 
My php coding is:

```
function csv_to_array($filename='', $delimiter=',')
{
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
    return FALSE;
    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
        {
            if(!$header)
            $header = $row;
            else
            $data[] = array_combine($header,$row);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $data;
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $count=0;
    $file_name=basename($_FILES['csv']['name']);
    $upload_path="upload_files/".time()."_".$file_name;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'], $upload_path);
    $file_path = 'upload_files/'.$file_name;
    $result = csv_to_array($file_path);
    foreach($result as $results)
    {
        $question=addslashes($results['question']);
        $que_img=addslashes($results['question_img']);
        $img_for=addslashes($results['img_for']);
        $option1=addslashes($results['option1']);
        $option2=addslashes($results['option2']);
        $option3=addslashes($results['option3']);
        $option4=addslashes($results['option4']);
        $corrct_ans=addslashes($results['correctanswer']);
        $justification=addslashes($results['justification']);
        $subject_id=$_POST['subjectid'];
        $pgroup=addslashes($results['pgroup']);
        $karea=addslashes($results['karea']);
        $mock=addslashes($results['mock']);
        $email_ins = "insert into online_questions(question,question_img,img_for,option1,option2,option3,option4,correctanswer,justification,subjectid,pgroup,karea,mock) values ('$question','$que_img','$img_for','$option1','$option2','$option3','$option4','$corrct_ans','$justification','$subject_id','$pgroup','$karea','$mock')";
        if(mysql_query($email_ins))
        {
            $count++;
        }
    }
    if($count!=0)
    {
         header("location:upload_questions.php?msg=success");
    }
    else 
    {
        //header("location:upload_questions.php?msg=error");
        $rightside .= '<div class="msg-error"><h4>Error:'.mysql_error().'</h4></div>';
    }
}
else 
{
    $rightside .= '<form method="POST">
    <fieldset><legend>Upload questions</legend>
    <ul class="align-list"><li><label for="test-username">Select Subject :</label>
    <select name="subjectid" class="required">
        <option>-----Select-----</option>
        <option value="8">PMP Preparatory Program</option>
        <option value="9">Primavera</option>
        <option value="10">Microsoft Project [MSP]</option>
   </select></li>
   <li><label for="test-username">Upload CSV : </label><input name="csv" type="file" /></li>
   <li><label for="test-username"></label><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></li>
   </fieldset></form>';
}
```

How can I get the file and filename of above html coding.

Answer (score 0):

try this:**EDITED**

```
<?php
function csv_to_array($filename='', $delimiter=',')
{
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
    return FALSE;
    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
        {
            if(!$header)
            $header = $row;
            else
            $data[] = array_combine($header,$row);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $data;
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $count=0;
    $file_name=$_FILES['csv']['name'];
    echo $_FILES['csv']['name'];
    $upload_path="upload_files/".time()."_".$file_name;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'], $upload_path);
    $file_path = 'upload_files/'.$file_name;
    echo $file_path;
    $result = csv_to_array($file_path);
    foreach($result as $results)
    {
        $question=addslashes($results['question']);
        $que_img=addslashes($results['question_img']);
        $img_for=addslashes($results['img_for']);
        $option1=addslashes($results['option1']);
        $option2=addslashes($results['option2']);
        $option3=addslashes($results['option3']);
        $option4=addslashes($results['option4']);
        $corrct_ans=addslashes($results['correctanswer']);
        $justification=addslashes($results['justification']);
        $subject_id=$_POST['subjectid'];
        $pgroup=addslashes($results['pgroup']);
        $karea=addslashes($results['karea']);
        $mock=addslashes($results['mock']);
        $email_ins = "insert into online_questions(question,question_img,img_for,option1,option2,option3,option4,correctanswer,justification,subjectid,pgroup,karea,mock) values ('$question','$que_img','$img_for','$option1','$option2','$option3','$option4','$corrct_ans','$justification','$subject_id','$pgroup','$karea','$mock')";
        if(mysql_query($email_ins))
        {
            $count++;
        }
    }
    if($count!=0)
    {
         header("location:upload_questions.php?msg=success");
    }
    else 
    {
        //header("location:upload_questions.php?msg=error");
        $rightside .= '<div class="msg-error"><h4>Error:'.mysql_error().'</h4></div>';
    }
}
else 
{
    $rightside .= '<form  method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset><legend>Upload questions</legend>
    <label for="test-username">Select Subject :</label>
    <select name="subjectid" class="required">
        <option>-----Select-----</option>
        <option value="8">PMP Preparatory Program</option>
        <option value="9">Primavera</option>
        <option value="10">Microsoft Project [MSP]</option>
   </select>
  <label for="test-username">Upload CSV : </label><input name="csv" type="file" />
   <label for="test-username"></label><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
   </fieldset></form>';
}
echo $rightside;

?>
```

i have removed li's you can add them.the problem was with your form tag i have changed it .

```
<form  method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```